How to apply background color to text in a TextBlock without affecting the entire TextBlock or using Run elements
I'm working with a TextBlock in WPF and need to apply a background color only to the text content without affecting the entire TextBlock. I don't want to use Run or Inline elements because this interferes with the tooltips (custom tooltip) that are applied.
What I have tried:
1.I created a ControlTemplate with a TextBlock inside it, and I applied a Style with triggers to change the background color based on certain conditions.
2.I tried to apply a Background directly to the TextBlock in the style, but this changes the background of the entire block, not just the text.
3.I tried using a DependencyProperty for highlighting, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
4.I also experimented with Run, Inline, and Span elements, but these interfere with the tooltip functionality when hovering over the text. 5. I have also tried by applying Border around the TextBlock and giving the BorderThichkness as 0, this applies background color to the rectangle area not just behind the text area in the TextBlock.
ControlTemplate and Style:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">     
<TextBlock FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CustomTextBlockId">         
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayText}" />     
</TextBlock>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">     
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>    
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipType" Value="Auto"/>     
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipHeader" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTip.ToolTipHeader}"/>     <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipBody" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTip.ToolTipBody}"/>     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>     
<Style.Triggers>         
<MultiDataTrigger>             
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                 
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Data.IsHighlighted, Source={StaticResource ViewModelProxy}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>                 
    <Condition Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SearchMatchText, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ViewModelProxy}}"/>            
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>             
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipType" Value="Auto"/>             
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipHeader" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTip.ToolTipHeader}"/>             
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipBody" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTip.ToolTipBody}"/>          
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>         
</MultiDataTrigger>         
<MultiDataTrigger>            
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                 
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Data.IsHighlighted, Source={StaticResource ViewModelProxy}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>                 
<Condition Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SearchMatchText, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ViewModelProxy}}"/>                 
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=VisibleInDisplay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Value="False"/>             
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>             
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>             
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CustomTextBrush}"/>         
</MultiDataTrigger>     
</Style.Triggers> </Style> 

What I need:
1.I want the background color to be applied to the entire text within the TextBlock, not the whole TextBlock container.
2.Tooltips should work when hovering over the text (the tooltip is customtooltip, defined in ToolTipService).

We don't know "ToolTipService.ToolTipType" and "ToolTipService.ToolTipHeader" and "ToolTipService.ToolTipBody". How we can think about the way to avoid the interference with unknown functions?

Sounds like you're trying to implement "SelectedText"; which is a programmable feature.
